# Spring ApplicationContext Beans-wiring

Tags: java, spring

I have two ApplicationContexts for my project (very huge project).
One old xml with data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans default-autowire="autodetect">
</beans>
```

now I need to add my other project applicatinContext to it or any other way so that none of the modules will be impacted

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="positionResponsesDAO"
    class="com.xxx.modules.worklist.DAO.Impl.PositionResponsesDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="positionDAO"
    class="com.xxx..modules.worklist.DAO.Impl.PositionDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="nextActionDAO"
    class="com.xxx..modules.worklist.DAO.Impl.NextActionDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
     <bean>
      ....... few more
     </bean>

   <bean id="workOrderManager" class="com.xxx.modules.worklist.action.manager.impl.WorkOrderManagerImpl">
    <property name="positionDO" ref="positionDO" />
    <property name="moveWorkOrderDO" ref="moveWorkOrderDO" />
    <property name="nextActionDO" ref="nextActionDO" />
    <property name="positionDAO" ref="positionDAO" />
    <property name="moveResponsesDAO" ref="moveResponsesDAO" />
    <property name="moveWorkOrderDAO" ref="moveWorkOrderDAO" />
    <property name="nextActionDAO" ref="nextActionDAO" />
    <property name="positionResponsesDAO" ref="positionResponsesDAO" />
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="driverUrl" />
    <property name="user" value="MCMGR" />
    <property name="password" value="MC123" />
</bean>
  </beans>
```

the first one has Auto-wiring enabled and this one has and needs manual wiring. How can i combined both of them to put into one xml or read two configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why reading two or more application context files is difficult.  The usual Spring idiom is to partition configuration according to layer.  I typically have configuration for persistence, service, web, etc.  If it's a web application, I just add all of them in using the `ContextLoaderListener`.  You can specify as many configuration files as you need.

I would consider one huge configuration file a liability in the same way that I would look down on one huge class for everything.  Decomposition is a computer science fundamental.  I'd recommend partitioning your configuration.

Mixing annotation-based and XML-based configuration isn't a problem, either.

You'll only have an issue if the two configurations overlap.  You'll have to remove one or the other for the conflicted beans.

Comment: I don't know what "without success" looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<import/>` tag. See http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?41811-Application-Context-and-include